# What do react-compare-app's npm install messages mean?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, npm-install

**Context**: I went to the [react-compare-app](https://github.com/Rhymond/product-compare-react) example from [React's examples page](https://reactjs.org/community/examples.html) and cloned the repo. After running `npm install` it started spitting out some lines that looked like most installs I've done, but then the text just started taking over my entire terminal and it didn't look like any install I've done in the past (granted I'm a novice).

**My question**: What was it doing? I got a little worried and stopped the process with `ctrl+c`.

Below is everything it showed before I ended it:

```
> node-sass@4.5.3 install /Users/ryangoree/workspace/javascript/react/examples/product-compare-react/node_modules/node-sass
> node scripts/install.js

Downloading binary from https://github.com/sass/node-sass/releases/download/v4.5.3/darwin-x64-59_binding.node
Cannot download "https://github.com/sass/node-sass/releases/download/v4.5.3/darwin-x64-59_binding.node": 

HTTP error 404 Not Found

Hint: If github.com is not accessible in your location
      try setting a proxy via HTTP_PROXY, e.g. 

      export HTTP_PROXY=http://example.com:1234

or configure npm proxy via

      npm config set proxy http://example.com:8080

> uglifyjs-webpack-plugin@0.4.6 postinstall /Users/ryangoree/workspace/javascript/react/examples/product-compare-react/node_modules/uglifyjs-webpack-plugin
> node lib/post_install.js


> node-sass@4.5.3 postinstall /Users/ryangoree/workspace/javascript/react/examples/product-compare-react/node_modules/node-sass
> node scripts/build.js

Building: /usr/local/Cellar/node/9.4.0/bin/node /Users/ryangoree/workspace/javascript/react/examples/product-compare-react/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js rebuild --verbose --libsass_ext= --libsass_cflags= --libsass_ldflags= --libsass_library=
gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
gyp verb cli [ '/usr/local/Cellar/node/9.4.0/bin/node',
gyp verb cli   '/Users/ryangoree/workspace/javascript/react/examples/product-compare-react/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js',
gyp verb cli   'rebuild',
gyp verb cli   '--verbose',
gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ext=',
gyp verb cli   '--libsass_cflags=',
gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ldflags=',
gyp verb cli   '--libsass_library=' ]
gyp info using node-gyp@3.6.2
gyp info using node@9.4.0 | darwin | x64
gyp verb command rebuild []
gyp verb command clean []
gyp verb clean removing "build" directory
gyp verb command configure []
gyp verb check python checking for Python executable "python2" in the PATH
gyp verb `which` succeeded python2 /usr/local/bin/python2
gyp verb check python version `/usr/local/bin/python2 -c "import platform; print(platform.python_version());"` returned: "2.7.14\n"
gyp verb get node dir no --target version specified, falling back to host node version: 9.4.0
gyp verb command install [ '9.4.0' ]
gyp verb install input version string "9.4.0"
gyp verb install installing version: 9.4.0
gyp verb install --ensure was passed, so won't reinstall if already installed
gyp verb install version is already installed, need to check "installVersion"
gyp verb got "installVersion" 9
gyp verb needs "installVersion" 9
gyp verb install version is good
gyp verb get node dir target node version installed: 9.4.0
gyp verb build dir attempting to create "build" dir: /Users/ryangoree/workspace/javascript/react/examples/product-compare-react/node_modules/node-sass/build
gyp verb build dir "build" dir needed to be created? /Users/ryangoree/workspace/javascript/react/examples/product-compare-react/node_modules/node-sass/build
gyp verb build/config.gypi creating config file
gyp verb build/config.gypi writing out config file: /Users/ryangoree/workspace/javascript/react/examples/product-compare-react/node_modules/node-sass/build/config.gypi
gyp verb config.gypi checking for gypi file: /Users/ryangoree/workspace/javascript/react/examples/product-compare-react/node_modules/node-sass/config.gypi
gyp verb common.gypi checking for gypi file: /Users/ryangoree/workspace/javascript/react/examples/product-compare-react/node_modules/node-sass/common.gypi
gyp verb gyp gyp format was not specified; forcing "make"
gyp info spawn /usr/local/bin/python2
gyp info spawn args [ '/Users/ryangoree/workspace/javascript/react/examples/product-compare-react/node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/gyp_main.py',
gyp info spawn args   'binding.gyp',
gyp info spawn args   '-f',
gyp info spawn args   'make',
gyp info spawn args   '-I',
gyp info spawn args   '/Users/ryangoree/workspace/javascript/react/examples/product-compare-react/node_modules/node-sass/build/config.gypi',
gyp info spawn args   '-I',
gyp info spawn args   '/Users/ryangoree/workspace/javascript/react/examples/product-compare-react/node_modules/node-gyp/addon.gypi',
gyp info spawn args   '-I',
gyp info spawn args   '/Users/ryangoree/.node-gyp/9.4.0/include/node/common.gypi',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dlibrary=shared_library',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dvisibility=default',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_root_dir=/Users/ryangoree/.node-gyp/9.4.0',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_gyp_dir=/Users/ryangoree/workspace/javascript/react/examples/product-compare-react/node_modules/node-gyp',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_lib_file=/Users/ryangoree/.node-gyp/9.4.0/<(target_arch)/node.lib',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dmodule_root_dir=/Users/ryangoree/workspace/javascript/react/examples/product-compare-react/node_modules/node-sass',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_engine=v8',
gyp info spawn args   '--depth=.',
gyp info spawn args   '--no-parallel',
gyp info spawn args   '--generator-output',
gyp info spawn args   'build',
gyp info spawn args   '-Goutput_dir=.' ]
xcode-select: error: tool 'xcodebuild' requires Xcode, but active developer directory '/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools' is a command line tools instance

xcode-select: error: tool 'xcodebuild' requires Xcode, but active developer directory '/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools' is a command line tools instance

gyp verb command build []
gyp verb build type Release
gyp verb architecture x64
gyp verb node dev dir /Users/ryangoree/.node-gyp/9.4.0
gyp verb `which` succeeded for `make` /usr/bin/make
gyp info spawn make
gyp info spawn args [ 'V=1', 'BUILDTYPE=Release', '-C', 'build' ]
  c++ '-DNODE_GYP_MODULE_NAME=libsass' '-DUSING_UV_SHARED=1' '-DUSING_V8_SHARED=1' '-DV8_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS=1' '-D_DARWIN_USE_64_BIT_INODE=1' '-D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE' '-D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64' '-DLIBSASS_VERSION="3.5.0.beta.2"' -I/Users/ryangoree/.node-gyp/9.4.0/include/node -I/Users/ryangoree/.node-gyp/9.4.0/src -I/Users/ryangoree/.node-gyp/9.4.0/deps/uv/include -I/Users/ryangoree/.node-gyp/9.4.0/deps/v8/include -I../src/libsass/include  -Os -gdwarf-2 -mmacosx-version-min=10.7 -arch x86_64 -Wall -Wendif-labels -W -Wno-unused-parameter -std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++ -fno-threadsafe-statics -fno-strict-aliasing -MMD -MF ./Release/.deps/Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/ast.o.d.raw   -c -o Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/ast.o ../src/libsass/src/ast.cpp
  c++ '-DNODE_GYP_MODULE_NAME=libsass' '-DUSING_UV_SHARED=1' '-DUSING_V8_SHARED=1' '-DV8_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS=1' '-D_DARWIN_USE_64_BIT_INODE=1' '-D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE' '-D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64' '-DLIBSASS_VERSION="3.5.0.beta.2"' -I/Users/ryangoree/.node-gyp/9.4.0/include/node -I/Users/ryangoree/.node-gyp/9.4.0/src -I/Users/ryangoree/.node-gyp/9.4.0/deps/uv/include -I/Users/ryangoree/.node-gyp/9.4.0/deps/v8/include -I../src/libsass/include  -Os -gdwarf-2 -mmacosx-version-min=10.7 -arch x86_64 -Wall -Wendif-labels -W -Wno-unused-parameter -std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++ -fno-threadsafe-statics -fno-strict-aliasing -MMD -MF ./Release/.deps/Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/ast_fwd_decl.o.d.raw   -c -o Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/ast_fwd_decl.o ../src/libsass/src/ast_fwd_decl.cpp
  c++ '-DNODE_GYP_MODULE_NAME=libsass' '-DUSING_UV_SHARED=1' '-DUSING_V8_SHARED=1' '-DV8_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS=1' '-D_DARWIN_USE_64_BIT_INODE=1' '-D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE' '-D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64' '-DLIBSASS_VERSION="3.5.0.beta.2"' -I/Users/ryangoree/.node-gyp/9.4.0/include/node -I/Users/ryangoree/.node-gyp/9.4.0/src -I/Users/ryangoree/.node-gyp/9.4.0/deps/uv/include -I/Users/ryangoree/.node-gyp/9.4.0/deps/v8/include -I../src/libsass/include  -Os -gdwarf-2 -mmacosx-version-min=10.7 -arch x86_64 -Wall -Wendif-labels -W -Wno-unused-parameter -std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++ -fno-threadsafe-statics -fno-strict-aliasing -MMD -MF ./Release/.deps/Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/base64vlq.o.d.raw   -c -o Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/base64vlq.o ../src/libsass/src/base64vlq.cpp
  c++ '-DNODE_GYP_MODULE_NAME=libsass' '-DUSING_UV_SHARED=1' '-DUSING_V8_SHARED=1' '-DV8_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS=1' '-D_DARWIN_USE_64_BIT_INODE=1' '-D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE' '-D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64' '-DLIBSASS_VERSION="3.5.0.beta.2"' -I/Users/ryangoree/.node-gyp/9.4.0/include/node -I/Users/ryangoree/.node-gyp/9.4.0/src -I/Users/ryangoree/.node-gyp/9.4.0/deps/uv/include -I/Users/ryangoree/.node-gyp/9.4.0/deps/v8/include -I../src/libsass/include  -Os -gdwarf-2 -mmacosx-version-min=10.7 -arch x86_64 -Wall -Wendif-labels -W -Wno-unused-parameter -std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++ -fno-threadsafe-statics -fno-strict-aliasing -MMD -MF ./Release/.deps/Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/bind.o.d.raw   -c -o Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/bind.o ../src/libsass/src/bind.cpp
  cc '-DNODE_GYP_MODULE_NAME=libsass' '-DUSING_UV_SHARED=1' '-DUSING_V8_SHARED=1' '-DV8_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS=1' '-D_DARWIN_USE_64_BIT_INODE=1' '-D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE' '-D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64' '-DLIBSASS_VERSION="3.5.0.beta.2"' -I/Users/ryangoree/.node-gyp/9.4.0/include/node -I/Users/ryangoree/.node-gyp/9.4.0/src -I/Users/ryangoree/.node-gyp/9.4.0/deps/uv/include -I/Users/ryangoree/.node-gyp/9.4.0/deps/v8/include -I../src/libsass/include  -Os -gdwarf-2 -mmacosx-version-min=10.7 -arch x86_64 -Wall -Wendif-labels -W -Wno-unused-parameter -fno-strict-aliasing -MMD -MF ./Release/.deps/Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/cencode.o.d.raw   -c -o Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/cencode.o ../src/libsass/src/cencode.c
  c++ '-DNODE_GYP_MODULE_NAME=libsass' '-DUSING_UV_SHARED=1' '-DUSING_V8_SHARED=1' '-DV8_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS=1' '-D_DARWIN_USE_64_BIT_INODE=1' '-D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE' '-D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64' '-DLIBSASS_VERSION="3.5.0.beta.2"' -I/Users/ryangoree/.node-gyp/9.4.0/include/node -I/Users/ryangoree/.node-gyp/9.4.0/src -I/Users/ryangoree/.node-gyp/9.4.0/deps/uv/include -I/Users/ryangoree/.node-gyp/9.4.0/deps/v8/include -I../src/libsass/include  -Os -gdwarf-2 -mmacosx-version-min=10.7 -arch x86_64 -Wall -Wendif-labels -W -Wno-unused-parameter -std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++ -fno-threadsafe-statics -fno-strict-aliasing -MMD -MF ./Release/.deps/Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/check_nesting.o.d.raw   -c -o Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/check_nesting.o ../src/libsass/src/check_nesting.cpp
  c++ '-DNODE_GYP_MODULE_NAME=libsass' '-DUSING_UV_SHARED=1' '-DUSING_V8_SHARED=1' '-DV8_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS=1' '-D_DARWIN_USE_64_BIT_INODE=1' '-D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE' '-D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64' '-DLIBSASS_VERSION="3.5.0.beta.2"' -I/Users/ryangoree/.node-gyp/9.4.0/include/node -I/Users/ryangoree/.node-gyp/9.4.0/src -I/Users/ryangoree/.node-gyp/9.4.0/deps/uv/include -I/Users/ryangoree/.node-gyp/9.4.0/deps/v8/include -I../src/libsass/include  -Os -gdwarf-2 -mmacosx-version-min=10.7 -arch x86_64 -Wall -Wendif-labels -W -Wno-unused-parameter -std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++ -fno-threadsafe-statics -fno-strict-aliasing -MMD -MF ./Release/.deps/Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/color_maps.o.d.raw   -c -o Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/color_maps.o ../src/libsass/src/color_maps.cpp
  c++ '-DNODE_GYP_MODULE_NAME=libsass' '-DUSING_UV_SHARED=1' '-DUSING_V8_SHARED=1' '-DV8_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS=1' '-D_DARWIN_USE_64_BIT_INODE=1' '-D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE' '-D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64' '-DLIBSASS_VERSION="3.5.0.beta.2"' -I/Users/ryangoree/.node-gyp/9.4.0/include/node -I/Users/ryangoree/.node-gyp/9.4.0/src -I/Users/ryangoree/.node-gyp/9.4.0/deps/uv/include -I/Users/ryangoree/.node-gyp/9.4.0/deps/v8/include -I../src/libsass/include  -Os -gdwarf-2 -mmacosx-version-min=10.7 -arch x86_64 -Wall -Wendif-labels -W -Wno-unused-parameter -std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++ -fno-threadsafe-statics -fno-strict-aliasing -MMD -MF ./Release/.deps/Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/constants.o.d.raw   -c -o Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/constants.o ../src/libsass/src/constants.cpp
  c++ '-DNODE_GYP_MODULE_NAME=libsass' '-DUSING_UV_SHARED=1' '-DUSING_V8_SHARED=1' '-DV8_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS=1' '-D_DARWIN_USE_64_BIT_INODE=1' '-D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE' '-D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64' '-DLIBSASS_VERSION="3.5.0.beta.2"' -I/Users/ryangoree/.node-gyp/9.4.0/include/node -I/Users/ryangoree/.node-gyp/9.4.0/src -I/Users/ryangoree/.node-gyp/9.4.0/deps/uv/include -I/Users/ryangoree/.node-gyp/9.4.0/deps/v8/include -I../src/libsass/include  -Os -gdwarf-2 -mmacosx-version-min=10.7 -arch x86_64 -Wall -Wendif-labels -W -Wno-unused-parameter -std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++ -fno-threadsafe-statics -fno-strict-aliasing -MMD -MF ./Release/.deps/Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/context.o.d.raw   -c -o Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/context.o ../src/libsass/src/context.cpp
  c++ '-DNODE_GYP_MODULE_NAME=libsass' '-DUSING_UV_SHARED=1' '-DUSING_V8_SHARED=1' '-DV8_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS=1' '-D_DARWIN_USE_64_BIT_INODE=1' '-D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE' '-D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64' '-DLIBSASS_VERSION="3.5.0.beta.2"' -I/Users/ryangoree/.node-gyp/9.4.0/include/node -I/Users/ryangoree/.node-gyp/9.4.0/src -I/Users/ryangoree/.node-gyp/9.4.0/deps/uv/include -I/Users/ryangoree/.node-gyp/9.4.0/deps/v8/include -I../src/libsass/include  -Os -gdwarf-2 -mmacosx-version-min=10.7 -arch x86_64 -Wall -Wendif-labels -W -Wno-unused-parameter -std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++ -fno-threadsafe-statics -fno-strict-aliasing -MMD -MF ./Release/.deps/Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/cssize.o.d.raw   -c -o Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/cssize.o ../src/libsass/src/cssize.cpp
  c++ '-DNODE_GYP_MODULE_NAME=libsass' '-DUSING_UV_SHARED=1' '-DUSING_V8_SHARED=1' '-DV8_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS=1' '-D_DARWIN_USE_64_BIT_INODE=1' '-D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE' '-D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64' '-DLIBSASS_VERSION="3.5.0.beta.2"' -I/Users/ryangoree/.node-gyp/9.4.0/include/node -I/Users/ryangoree/.node-gyp/9.4.0/src -I/Users/ryangoree/.node-gyp/9.4.0/deps/uv/include -I/Users/ryangoree/.node-gyp/9.4.0/deps/v8/include -I../src/libsass/include  -Os -gdwarf-2 -mmacosx-version-min=10.7 -arch x86_64 -Wall -Wendif-labels -W -Wno-unused-parameter -std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++ -fno-threadsafe-statics -fno-strict-aliasing -MMD -MF ./Release/.deps/Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/emitter.o.d.raw   -c -o Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/emitter.o ../src/libsass/src/emitter.cpp
  c++ '-DNODE_GYP_MODULE_NAME=libsass' '-DUSING_UV_SHARED=1' '-DUSING_V8_SHARED=1' '-DV8_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS=1' '-D_DARWIN_USE_64_BIT_INODE=1' '-D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE' '-D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64' '-DLIBSASS_VERSION="3.5.0.beta.2"' -I/Users/ryangoree/.node-gyp/9.4.0/include/node -I/Users/ryangoree/.node-gyp/9.4.0/src -I/Users/ryangoree/.node-gyp/9.4.0/deps/uv/include -I/Users/ryangoree/.node-gyp/9.4.0/deps/v8/include -I../src/libsass/include  -Os -gdwarf-2 -mmacosx-version-min=10.7 -arch x86_64 -Wall -Wendif-labels -W -Wno-unused-parameter -std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++ -fno-threadsafe-statics -fno-strict-aliasing -MMD -MF ./Release/.deps/Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/environment.o.d.raw   -c -o Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/environment.o ../src/libsass/src/environment.cpp
  c++ '-DNODE_GYP_MODULE_NAME=libsass' '-DUSING_UV_SHARED=1' '-DUSING_V8_SHARED=1' '-DV8_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS=1' '-D_DARWIN_USE_64_BIT_INODE=1' '-D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE' '-D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64' '-DLIBSASS_VERSION="3.5.0.beta.2"' -I/Users/ryangoree/.node-gyp/9.4.0/include/node -I/Users/ryangoree/.node-gyp/9.4.0/src -I/Users/ryangoree/.node-gyp/9.4.0/deps/uv/include -I/Users/ryangoree/.node-gyp/9.4.0/deps/v8/include -I../src/libsass/include  -Os -gdwarf-2 -mmacosx-version-min=10.7 -arch x86_64 -Wall -Wendif-labels -W -Wno-unused-parameter -std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++ -fno-threadsafe-statics -fno-strict-aliasing -MMD -MF ./Release/.deps/Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/error_handling.o.d.raw   -c -o Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/error_handling.o ../src/libsass/src/error_handling.cpp
  c++ '-DNODE_GYP_MODULE_NAME=libsass' '-DUSING_UV_SHARED=1' '-DUSING_V8_SHARED=1' '-DV8_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS=1' '-D_DARWIN_USE_64_BIT_INODE=1' '-D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE' '-D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64' '-DLIBSASS_VERSION="3.5.0.beta.2"' -I/Users/ryangoree/.node-gyp/9.4.0/include/node -I/Users/ryangoree/.node-gyp/9.4.0/src -I/Users/ryangoree/.node-gyp/9.4.0/deps/uv/include -I/Users/ryangoree/.node-gyp/9.4.0/deps/v8/include -I../src/libsass/include  -Os -gdwarf-2 -mmacosx-version-min=10.7 -arch x86_64 -Wall -Wendif-labels -W -Wno-unused-parameter -std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++ -fno-threadsafe-statics -fno-strict-aliasing -MMD -MF ./Release/.deps/Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/eval.o.d.raw   -c -o Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/eval.o ../src/libsass/src/eval.cpp
  c++ '-DNODE_GYP_MODULE_NAME=libsass' '-DUSING_UV_SHARED=1' '-DUSING_V8_SHARED=1' '-DV8_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS=1' '-D_DARWIN_USE_64_BIT_INODE=1' '-D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE' '-D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64' '-DLIBSASS_VERSION="3.5.0.beta.2"' -I/Users/ryangoree/.node-gyp/9.4.0/include/node -I/Users/ryangoree/.node-gyp/9.4.0/src -I/Users/ryangoree/.node-gyp/9.4.0/deps/uv/include -I/Users/ryangoree/.node-gyp/9.4.0/deps/v8/include -I../src/libsass/include  -Os -gdwarf-2 -mmacosx-version-min=10.7 -arch x86_64 -Wall -Wendif-labels -W -Wno-unused-parameter -std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++ -fno-threadsafe-statics -fno-strict-aliasing -MMD -MF ./Release/.deps/Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/expand.o.d.raw   -c -o Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/expand.o ../src/libsass/src/expand.cpp
  c++ '-DNODE_GYP_MODULE_NAME=libsass' '-DUSING_UV_SHARED=1' '-DUSING_V8_SHARED=1' '-DV8_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS=1' '-D_DARWIN_USE_64_BIT_INODE=1' '-D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE' '-D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64' '-DLIBSASS_VERSION="3.5.0.beta.2"' -I/Users/ryangoree/.node-gyp/9.4.0/include/node -I/Users/ryangoree/.node-gyp/9.4.0/src -I/Users/ryangoree/.node-gyp/9.4.0/deps/uv/include -I/Users/ryangoree/.node-gyp/9.4.0/deps/v8/include -I../src/libsass/include  -Os -gdwarf-2 -mmacosx-version-min=10.7 -arch x86_64 -Wall -Wendif-labels -W -Wno-unused-parameter -std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++ -fno-threadsafe-statics -fno-strict-aliasing -MMD -MF ./Release/.deps/Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/extend.o.d.raw   -c -o Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/extend.o ../src/libsass/src/extend.cpp
  c++ '-DNODE_GYP_MODULE_NAME=libsass' '-DUSING_UV_SHARED=1' '-DUSING_V8_SHARED=1' '-DV8_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS=1' '-D_DARWIN_USE_64_BIT_INODE=1' '-D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE' '-D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64' '-DLIBSASS_VERSION="3.5.0.beta.2"' -I/Users/ryangoree/.node-gyp/9.4.0/include/node -I/Users/ryangoree/.node-gyp/9.4.0/src -I/Users/ryangoree/.node-gyp/9.4.0/deps/uv/include -I/Users/ryangoree/.node-gyp/9.4.0/deps/v8/include -I../src/libsass/include  -Os -gdwarf-2 -mmacosx-version-min=10.7 -arch x86_64 -Wall -Wendif-labels -W -Wno-unused-parameter -std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++ -fno-threadsafe-statics -fno-strict-aliasing -MMD -MF ./Release/.deps/Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/file.o.d.raw   -c -o Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/file.o ../src/libsass/src/file.cpp
  c++ '-DNODE_GYP_MODULE_NAME=libsass' '-DUSING_UV_SHARED=1' '-DUSING_V8_SHARED=1' '-DV8_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS=1' '-D_DARWIN_USE_64_BIT_INODE=1' '-D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE' '-D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64' '-DLIBSASS_VERSION="3.5.0.beta.2"' -I/Users/ryangoree/.node-gyp/9.4.0/include/node -I/Users/ryangoree/.node-gyp/9.4.0/src -I/Users/ryangoree/.node-gyp/9.4.0/deps/uv/include -I/Users/ryangoree/.node-gyp/9.4.0/deps/v8/include -I../src/libsass/include  -Os -gdwarf-2 -mmacosx-version-min=10.7 -arch x86_64 -Wall -Wendif-labels -W -Wno-unused-parameter -std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++ -fno-threadsafe-statics -fno-strict-aliasing -MMD -MF ./Release/.deps/Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/functions.o.d.raw   -c -o Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/functions.o ../src/libsass/src/functions.cpp
  c++ '-DNODE_GYP_MODULE_NAME=libsass' '-DUSING_UV_SHARED=1' '-DUSING_V8_SHARED=1' '-DV8_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS=1' '-D_DARWIN_USE_64_BIT_INODE=1' '-D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE' '-D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64' '-DLIBSASS_VERSION="3.5.0.beta.2"' -I/Users/ryangoree/.node-gyp/9.4.0/include/node -I/Users/ryangoree/.node-gyp/9.4.0/src -I/Users/ryangoree/.node-gyp/9.4.0/deps/uv/include -I/Users/ryangoree/.node-gyp/9.4.0/deps/v8/include -I../src/libsass/include  -Os -gdwarf-2 -mmacosx-version-min=10.7 -arch x86_64 -Wall -Wendif-labels -W -Wno-unused-parameter -std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++ -fno-threadsafe-statics -fno-strict-aliasing -MMD -MF ./Release/.deps/Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/inspect.o.d.raw   -c -o Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/inspect.o ../src/libsass/src/inspect.cpp
  c++ '-DNODE_GYP_MODULE_NAME=libsass' '-DUSING_UV_SHARED=1' '-DUSING_V8_SHARED=1' '-DV8_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS=1' '-D_DARWIN_USE_64_BIT_INODE=1' '-D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE' '-D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64' '-DLIBSASS_VERSION="3.5.0.beta.2"' -I/Users/ryangoree/.node-gyp/9.4.0/include/node -I/Users/ryangoree/.node-gyp/9.4.0/src -I/Users/ryangoree/.node-gyp/9.4.0/deps/uv/include -I/Users/ryangoree/.node-gyp/9.4.0/deps/v8/include -I../src/libsass/include  -Os -gdwarf-2 -mmacosx-version-min=10.7 -arch x86_64 -Wall -Wendif-labels -W -Wno-unused-parameter -std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++ -fno-threadsafe-statics -fno-strict-aliasing -MMD -MF ./Release/.deps/Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/json.o.d.raw   -c -o Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/json.o ../src/libsass/src/json.cpp
  c++ '-DNODE_GYP_MODULE_NAME=libsass' '-DUSING_UV_SHARED=1' '-DUSING_V8_SHARED=1' '-DV8_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS=1' '-D_DARWIN_USE_64_BIT_INODE=1' '-D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE' '-D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64' '-DLIBSASS_VERSION="3.5.0.beta.2"' -I/Users/ryangoree/.node-gyp/9.4.0/include/node -I/Users/ryangoree/.node-gyp/9.4.0/src -I/Users/ryangoree/.node-gyp/9.4.0/deps/uv/include -I/Users/ryangoree/.node-gyp/9.4.0/deps/v8/include -I../src/libsass/include  -Os -gdwarf-2 -mmacosx-version-min=10.7 -arch x86_64 -Wall -Wendif-labels -W -Wno-unused-parameter -std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++ -fno-threadsafe-statics -fno-strict-aliasing -MMD -MF ./Release/.deps/Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/lexer.o.d.raw   -c -o Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/lexer.o ../src/libsass/src/lexer.cpp
  c++ '-DNODE_GYP_MODULE_NAME=libsass' '-DUSING_UV_SHARED=1' '-DUSING_V8_SHARED=1' '-DV8_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS=1' '-D_DARWIN_USE_64_BIT_INODE=1' '-D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE' '-D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64' '-DLIBSASS_VERSION="3.5.0.beta.2"' -I/Users/ryangoree/.node-gyp/9.4.0/include/node -I/Users/ryangoree/.node-gyp/9.4.0/src -I/Users/ryangoree/.node-gyp/9.4.0/deps/uv/include -I/Users/ryangoree/.node-gyp/9.4.0/deps/v8/include -I../src/libsass/include  -Os -gdwarf-2 -mmacosx-version-min=10.7 -arch x86_64 -Wall -Wendif-labels -W -Wno-unused-parameter -std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++ -fno-threadsafe-statics -fno-strict-aliasing -MMD -MF ./Release/.deps/Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/listize.o.d.raw   -c -o Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/listize.o ../src/libsass/src/listize.cpp
  c++ '-DNODE_GYP_MODULE_NAME=libsass' '-DUSING_UV_SHARED=1' '-DUSING_V8_SHARED=1' '-DV8_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS=1' '-D_DARWIN_USE_64_BIT_INODE=1' '-D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE' '-D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64' '-DLIBSASS_VERSION="3.5.0.beta.2"' -I/Users/ryangoree/.node-gyp/9.4.0/include/node -I/Users/ryangoree/.node-gyp/9.4.0/src -I/Users/ryangoree/.node-gyp/9.4.0/deps/uv/include -I/Users/ryangoree/.node-gyp/9.4.0/deps/v8/include -I../src/libsass/include  -Os -gdwarf-2 -mmacosx-version-min=10.7 -arch x86_64 -Wall -Wendif-labels -W -Wno-unused-parameter -std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++ -fno-threadsafe-statics -fno-strict-aliasing -MMD -MF ./Release/.deps/Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/memory/SharedPtr.o.d.raw   -c -o Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/memory/SharedPtr.o ../src/libsass/src/memory/SharedPtr.cpp
  c++ '-DNODE_GYP_MODULE_NAME=libsass' '-DUSING_UV_SHARED=1' '-DUSING_V8_SHARED=1' '-DV8_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS=1' '-D_DARWIN_USE_64_BIT_INODE=1' '-D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE' '-D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64' '-DLIBSASS_VERSION="3.5.0.beta.2"' -I/Users/ryangoree/.node-gyp/9.4.0/include/node -I/Users/ryangoree/.node-gyp/9.4.0/src -I/Users/ryangoree/.node-gyp/9.4.0/deps/uv/include -I/Users/ryangoree/.node-gyp/9.4.0/deps/v8/include -I../src/libsass/include  -Os -gdwarf-2 -mmacosx-version-min=10.7 -arch x86_64 -Wall -Wendif-labels -W -Wno-unused-parameter -std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++ -fno-threadsafe-statics -fno-strict-aliasing -MMD -MF ./Release/.deps/Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/node.o.d.raw   -c -o Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/node.o ../src/libsass/src/node.cpp
  c++ '-DNODE_GYP_MODULE_NAME=libsass' '-DUSING_UV_SHARED=1' '-DUSING_V8_SHARED=1' '-DV8_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS=1' '-D_DARWIN_USE_64_BIT_INODE=1' '-D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE' '-D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64' '-DLIBSASS_VERSION="3.5.0.beta.2"' -I/Users/ryangoree/.node-gyp/9.4.0/include/node -I/Users/ryangoree/.node-gyp/9.4.0/src -I/Users/ryangoree/.node-gyp/9.4.0/deps/uv/include -I/Users/ryangoree/.node-gyp/9.4.0/deps/v8/include -I../src/libsass/include  -Os -gdwarf-2 -mmacosx-version-min=10.7 -arch x86_64 -Wall -Wendif-labels -W -Wno-unused-parameter -std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++ -fno-threadsafe-statics -fno-strict-aliasing -MMD -MF ./Release/.deps/Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/output.o.d.raw   -c -o Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/output.o ../src/libsass/src/output.cpp
  c++ '-DNODE_GYP_MODULE_NAME=libsass' '-DUSING_UV_SHARED=1' '-DUSING_V8_SHARED=1' '-DV8_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS=1' '-D_DARWIN_USE_64_BIT_INODE=1' '-D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE' '-D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64' '-DLIBSASS_VERSION="3.5.0.beta.2"' -I/Users/ryangoree/.node-gyp/9.4.0/include/node -I/Users/ryangoree/.node-gyp/9.4.0/src -I/Users/ryangoree/.node-gyp/9.4.0/deps/uv/include -I/Users/ryangoree/.node-gyp/9.4.0/deps/v8/include -I../src/libsass/include  -Os -gdwarf-2 -mmacosx-version-min=10.7 -arch x86_64 -Wall -Wendif-labels -W -Wno-unused-parameter -std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++ -fno-threadsafe-statics -fno-strict-aliasing -MMD -MF ./Release/.deps/Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/parser.o.d.raw   -c -o Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/parser.o ../src/libsass/src/parser.cpp
  c++ '-DNODE_GYP_MODULE_NAME=libsass' '-DUSING_UV_SHARED=1' '-DUSING_V8_SHARED=1' '-DV8_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS=1' '-D_DARWIN_USE_64_BIT_INODE=1' '-D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE' '-D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64' '-DLIBSASS_VERSION="3.5.0.beta.2"' -I/Users/ryangoree/.node-gyp/9.4.0/include/node -I/Users/ryangoree/.node-gyp/9.4.0/src -I/Users/ryangoree/.node-gyp/9.4.0/deps/uv/include -I/Users/ryangoree/.node-gyp/9.4.0/deps/v8/include -I../src/libsass/include  -Os -gdwarf-2 -mmacosx-version-min=10.7 -arch x86_64 -Wall -Wendif-labels -W -Wno-unused-parameter -std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++ -fno-threadsafe-statics -fno-strict-aliasing -MMD -MF ./Release/.deps/Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/plugins.o.d.raw   -c -o Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/plugins.o ../src/libsass/src/plugins.cpp
  c++ '-DNODE_GYP_MODULE_NAME=libsass' '-DUSING_UV_SHARED=1' '-DUSING_V8_SHARED=1' '-DV8_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS=1' '-D_DARWIN_USE_64_BIT_INODE=1' '-D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE' '-D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64' '-DLIBSASS_VERSION="3.5.0.beta.2"' -I/Users/ryangoree/.node-gyp/9.4.0/include/node -I/Users/ryangoree/.node-gyp/9.4.0/src -I/Users/ryangoree/.node-gyp/9.4.0/deps/uv/include -I/Users/ryangoree/.node-gyp/9.4.0/deps/v8/include -I../src/libsass/include  -Os -gdwarf-2 -mmacosx-version-min=10.7 -arch x86_64 -Wall -Wendif-labels -W -Wno-unused-parameter -std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++ -fno-threadsafe-statics -fno-strict-aliasing -MMD -MF ./Release/.deps/Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/position.o.d.raw   -c -o Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/position.o ../src/libsass/src/position.cpp
  c++ '-DNODE_GYP_MODULE_NAME=libsass' '-DUSING_UV_SHARED=1' '-DUSING_V8_SHARED=1' '-DV8_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS=1' '-D_DARWIN_USE_64_BIT_INODE=1' '-D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE' '-D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64' '-DLIBSASS_VERSION="3.5.0.beta.2"' -I/Users/ryangoree/.node-gyp/9.4.0/include/node -I/Users/ryangoree/.node-gyp/9.4.0/src -I/Users/ryangoree/.node-gyp/9.4.0/deps/uv/include -I/Users/ryangoree/.node-gyp/9.4.0/deps/v8/include -I../src/libsass/include  -Os -gdwarf-2 -mmacosx-version-min=10.7 -arch x86_64 -Wall -Wendif-labels -W -Wno-unused-parameter -std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++ -fno-threadsafe-statics -fno-strict-aliasing -MMD -MF ./Release/.deps/Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/prelexer.o.d.raw   -c -o Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/prelexer.o ../src/libsass/src/prelexer.cpp
^Cmake: *** [Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/prelexer.o] Interrupt: 2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I take a look at the output you posted, I think you were concered about the last few lines?

At this time node was compiling some native addons with node-gyp.

> node-gyp is a cross-platform command-line tool written in Node.js for
>   compiling native addon modules for Node.js.

For further information to node-gyp refer to this link:
https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp

When I correctly interpret the output, node-gyp was currently handling sass files before you aborted.

> Sass is the most mature, stable, and powerful professional grade CSS
>   extension language in the world.

Further information to sass you can find here:
https://sass-lang.com

Node-gyp uses (on *unix) make and gcc to compile native addons.

> The GNU Compiler Collection includes front ends for C, C++,
>   Objective-C, Fortran, Ada, and Go, as well as libraries for these
>   languages (libstdc++,...).

For more information about GCC use the link below:
https://gcc.gnu.org